# Icon to the comboboxes in CSS

Tags: html, css

I try to add some flags to specific combobox elements (something like 'warning', 'error' etc).

The idea is that I should mark with a flag the combo elements, generated with the "status" attribute (later I will classify the statuses)

The "test" div does work - a right aligned flag appears after it.. but this is not the case of the combo elements.

What it is possible to do?

```css
* {border: 1px dotted;}
[status]::after {
  content: "\02691"; 
  float: right; 
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>New-York</option>
  <option status="1">Paris</option>
  <option status="2">York</option>
  <option status="3">Old-York</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<div status>test</div>
```

Comment: Did you want the flag to appear after each option or at the end of the select dropdown?

Comment: like the "test" div does, the flag should be right aligned

Comment: Yeah I don't think you can add pseudo elements to option tags