# Combobox with an icon

Tags: html, css, asp.net

After [asking about the pseudo-elements in a HTML select (combobox)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57413476/961631) actually I wonder if is there a way to add directly the `span` elements inside a `select`'s `option` in order to add some colors/pictures nearby the option's text?

[image]

it seems simple code like `<option>New-York <span class='red'>red</span></option>` does not work...

What is the classic way to build such boxes?

I know there are [drop-down boxes in bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/dropdowns/), but I need it to behave like a combo (change value if selected)

PS. I use Bootstrap; also ASP.NET Core in background...

**PPS**. Here is some [codepen I tested](https://codepen.io/serhio/pen/WVzaPY?editors=1010)

Comment: https://select2.org/

Comment: if you want any kind of custom select dropdown in appearance or functionality you'll probably always have to go with a javascript plugin like select2. Will still work fine with your .net model binding. You can even create your own TagHelper for .net core, thats what I did

Comment: @zgood, I am newbie in that field what could you recommend to read about taghelpers in ASP .NET and how can they be applied in my case? thanks

Comment: @Serge I used this [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JezekT.AspNetCore.Select2) for a select2 taghelper and pretty much forked his project to make my own modifications. You can read more about creating taghelpers [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: But also you don't _need_ to create a taghelper, you can just use the javascript library that @TemaniAfif linked... its the same thing and might be easier for someone new